# Prove or disprove that the power of positive term polynomial will be eventually single peak

Tags: inequality, polynomials

This is a question that a classmate asked me three years ago.

Let $P(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i$ be a polynomial such that each $a_i>0$. Prove or disprove that there exists a positive integer $r$ such that $P(x)^r=\sum_{i=0}^{nr} b_ix^i$ and there exists $0\le j\le nr$ such that $b_0\le b_1\le \dots\le b_{j}$ and $b_{j+1}\ge\dots\ge b_{nr}$.

This problem may have a probability problem as its original problem, since the classmate asked this while taking a probability class. What I could do is to try to apply CLT to claim that the "central terms" has only one peak and try to select some $r$ to make the first few terms and last few terms increasing/decreasing (that is, I proved that I can choose an $r$ to make $b_0\le b_1\le\dots \le b_k$ for any $k$, and same at the other side). But I failed to prove the problem... I also tried to factorize it into smaller quadratic polynomials but also failed... Also, I can't come up with a counterexample, too...

Note: if polynomials $p,q$ are single peak, this DOES NOT imply that $pq$ is single peak. For example: $p(x)=1+x+100x^2$ and $q(x)=10000+10000x+10100x^2+9000x^3+9000x^4$. But $p(x)q(x)=900000x^6+909000x^5+1028000x^4+1019100x^3+1020100x^2+20000x+10000$

P.S. As @ChrisSanders in the comment points out, I have asked this question [here in Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417928/prove-or-disprove-that-the-power-of-positive-term-polynomial-will-be-eventually)

P.P.S. It is already answered [there in Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417928/prove-or-disprove-that-the-power-of-positive-term-polynomial-will-be-eventually).

Comment: It's worth looking it up to see if it comes from an undergraduate competition like Putnam or Miklos Schweitzer.

Comment: @ChrisSanders I am quite sure that it is not from a competition... Although it looks like one of the problems there.

Comment: I think this is interesting enough to post on Math Overflow

Comment: Without loss in generality, we can assume that $\sum_i a_i = 1$, i.e. that $a_i$ corresponds to the probability that $i$ is drawn. Then $b_i$ corresponds to the probability that the sum of $r$ independent draws is equal to $i$. The predominent sum value will correspond to $i = r m$, where $m$ is the mean value $m = \sum_i i\,a_i$. Then intuitively, the result seems correct. A formal rigourous demonstration is another thing.

Comment: @ChrisSanders Thanks, I will do it!

Comment: @Damien Thank you for saying this probability part, this is exactly what I mean for "try to apply CLT to claim that the "central terms" has only one peak "...